# how to pass parametes to the shell script

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I have some alias:

```
alias a1='ssh -A -t -p 22 user1@10.62.0.20 ssh user2@10.62.0.100'
```

and I have some shell script s1.sh, which gets different parameters.
This parameters I need pass through variable: $args

```
args="a1 b2 c3 d4"
cat s1.sh | a1 "sudo su - user3; /bin/sh -s $args"
```

This code work, script executed, but not pass parameters "/bin/sh -s $args" to s1.sh script.
How to pass "$args" variable in this example?

Comment: cat will simply print the commands in the script file and execute them on the remote machine, It will not be able to interpret arguments. You will need to scp the script to the remote machine and then execute with the arguments appended,

Comment: @barmaley : Your alias definition does not contain anything which possibly can be expanded. Hence, `a1 foo bar` simply appends `foo bar` to what the alias definition says.

Comment: You should use a function, not an alias. You also probably don't need either, as you can simply specify all the necessary flags and options in your `.ssh` configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
alias a1='ssh -A -t -p 22 -J user1@10.62.0.20 user2@10.62.0.100'
< s1.sh a1 "sudo -u user3 /bin/sh -s $args"
```

or better:

```
args=(a1 b2 c3 d4)
< s1.sh a1 "sudo -u user3 /bin/sh -s $(printf "%q " "{args[@]}"
# or double-escape, I am never sure in ssh-ing:
< s1.sh a1 "sudo -u user3 /bin/sh -s $(printf "%q" "$(printf "%q " "{args[@]}")")"
```

With `ssh ... ssh .. sudo su sh` you will be like 4-time re-evalulating input.

Also your `sh -s $args` is completely ignored - all input is eaten up by the shell started by `sudo`, and then nothing is left for `sh -s`. Also, `sudo su` is like `echo $(echo $(echo)))`. It already does `sudo`, so change the user with `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone..

I found solution.

This command doesn't work:

```
cat s1.sh | a1 "sudo su - user3; /bin/sh -s $args"
```

This command is work:

```
cat s1.sh | a1 "sudo -i -u user3 /bin/sh -s $args"
```